# Why checkbox inside jquery datatable is not working?

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatables

I have done server side processing in jquery.
There is a checkbox. When the checkbox is checked some buttons are supposed to be popped.

While in blade file it works. 
Like in blade file

```
<input type="checkbox" class="cv">
```

but inside jquery datatable it doesn't work.

```
Jquery Code
var $dlt = $('#delete').hide();

$delete = $('.cv').on("click",function(){
  $dlt.toggle($delete.is(":checked"));
});
```

```
Jquery datatable code
 $nestedData['options'] = "<input type='checkbox' data-id='{{$result->id}}' class='cv'>";
```

It doesn't work. The cv class won't trigger in jquery from the datatable checkbox.
But when i do it from blade file it works.

Answer (score 0):

You must be loading on click script before datatable load.
Handle the inputbox under datatable with dynamically created element click event handler

```
$delete = $(document).on("click",".cv",function(){
  $dlt.toggle($delete.is(":checked"));
});
```

Comment: i have loaded this script before the datatable loads but doesn't work.

Comment: can you recreate this problem on code snippet or jsfiddle, so that i can take a look at it